# Authenticating Users with Password in React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, react-native, express

Guys I have some general questions about interacting with my PostgreSQL DB my ExpressJS API and my React Native Frontend.

I managed to write some queries that for example check if the username that is entered in my RN app matches the one that is on the DB and returns its userID.

I know that on my DB every User has its Password that is being stored inside the DB in a hashed way.

How would a Query look like that would return for example the userID as I am doing it but only if the username exists and it matches the Password that is stored on the DB?

Do I need to know how the passwords are hashed on the DB?

The Query for userid:

```
    static getUserId (username, callback) {
    db.query(`SELECT userid FROM employee WHERE username = '${username}'`, (err, res)=> {
        if(err.error){
            return callback(err.error)
        } else {
            return callback(res)
        }
    })
}
```

The passwords are saved in the same employee table under password.

EDIT: I think I can take two WHERE statements like this:

```
`SELECT userid FROM employee WHERE username = '${username}' AND WHERE password = '${password}'`
```

but if a User enters his password inside the app it is not hashed so do I need to send the same hash method to compare these values?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards Faded.

Comment: So is there really no one who can give me a hint or some tips at least ? :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bcrypt.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) for hashing your passwords.

To hash password in **SignUp.js**:

```
app.post('/signup',(req,res,next)=> {
 //Password from request body of register request
    const myPlaintextPassword = req.body.password
    //saltRounds are typically set to 12
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
      // Store hash in your password DB with INSERT.
    });
}
```

Now to compare with Hash in **Login.js**:

```
app.post('/login',async (req,res,next)=>{
const existingUser = await db.query(`SELECT userid FROM employee WHERE username = '${username}'`, (err, res)=> {
        if(err.error){
            return callback(err.error)
        } else {
            return callback(res)
        }
    })
    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, existingUser.password);
if (!valid) {
        res.status(401).send('Wrong pass');
        return req.next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So even tho I want to get the user and his pw I need to send a POST request? and also do you know how to query for both ? username and pass like the query in my Edit? Because that query gives me psql error and im not sure if it is written wrong or if my backend handels 2 params wrong.

Comment: Actually I got my query to work just need to handle all Hashing stuff now.

Comment: You can use GET, but the reason I used POST is that you are going to send usename and password with your HTTP request, so that data is better sent with body than in URL, thats why POST. And to answer second part, you can add multiple conditions simply like: SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE [condition1] AND [consition2];

Comment: what is `saltRounds`?

Comment: Basically hashing rounds, higher the saltrounds, more time it takes to generate hash but makes brute forcing difficult

Answer (score 0):

You need to hash the incoming password and compare the two hashes.

That being said: if this is going to be at all used by real people I would suggest using a library to handle your auth instead of writing your own.  There are a lot of things that can go wrong to make your application insecure.